How do I check which email was verified when verifying the current and new email when updating an email in Supabase?
I am working on an email confirmation page for the two-step email verification process in Supabase when updating an email. To enhance the user experience, I want to display which email has been verified and provide a hint about the email that is still pending verification.
However, Supabase does not provide any extra details in the URL parameters or elsewhere, which makes this challenging. One way to determine if the verification process is fully completed (i.e., both emails are verified, and the email has been changed) is by checking if the user is logged out, as Supabase automatically logs you out once the email has been verified.
To make some progress, I have included the old and new email addresses as oldEmail and newEmail URL parameters. This way, we can at least pass some information through the URL.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
